# How to import paths or compile openssl in STMCube IDE?

Tags: openssl, stm32, cortex-m, stm32cubeide

I want to use one of the openssl pkey demos code on STMCube IDE and I am running into errors. I think I'm using wrong paths or not including makefile stuff in my IDE. I need help with that.

I keep getting errors of undefined reference to openssl functions like:

*undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_keygen_init'*

*undefined reference to `OSSL_PARAM_construct_utf8_string'*

I have included these paths in STM32CubeIDE project Properties > MCU GCC Compiler > Include Paths:

```
/usr/local/lib

/usr/lib -lssl -lcrypto

/usr/local/ssl/lib

/usr/local/bin/openssl
```

Make file in the demo is like this:

```
#
# To run the demos when linked with a shared library (default):
#
#    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../.. ./EVP_PKEY_EC_keygen
#    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../.. ./EVP_PKEY_RSA_keygen
#    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../.. ./EVP_PKEY_DSA_keygen
#    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../.. ./EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramgen
#    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../.. ./EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramvalidate
#    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../.. ./EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramfromdata

CFLAGS = -I../../include -g -Wall
LDFLAGS = -L../..
LDLIBS = -lcrypto

all: EVP_PKEY_EC_keygen EVP_PKEY_RSA_keygen EVP_PKEY_DSA_keygen \
     EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramgen EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramvalidate EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramfromdata \

%.o: %.c dsa.inc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $<

EVP_PKEY_EC_keygen: EVP_PKEY_EC_keygen.o

EVP_PKEY_RSA_keygen: EVP_PKEY_RSA_keygen.o

EVP_PKEY_DSA_keygen: EVP_PKEY_DSA_keygen.o

EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramgen: EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramgen.o

EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramvalidate: EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramvalidate.o

EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramfromdata: EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramfromdata.o

test: ;

clean:
    $(RM) *.o EVP_PKEY_EC_keygen EVP_PKEY_RSA_keygen EVP_PKEY_DSA_keygen \
          EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramgen EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramfromdata EVP_PKEY_DSA_paramvalidate
```